# jsp file not refreshing content coming from servlet.please any one help me

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

***i want to call servlet from javascript and then servlet will pass data to jsp page which in turn display that data.i've tried all thing but failed.please any one help me.tnx in advance***

Comment: it will be easier to help if you describe what you have tried

Comment: please post some code and tell us what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery ajax? All you need to do is import the latest jQuery plugin into your jsp file and do it like this in your javascript.

```
function updateData(){ 
     $.ajax({
          url: "ur_servlet_url&value="+any_value_to_pass,              
          type: "POST", 
          success: function(data){
               alert(data);
          } 
     });
  }
```

Here this will send the request to your servlet and returns the composed data whatever you like. Finally you can display your data like `$("#your_div_id").html(data);`. Let me know if this helps. Also post your code by edit your question, help us to get you the best answer.